# Does a getter( ) to shared data that doesn't change need to be synchronized?

Tags: java, synchronization

Imagine I have this class:

```
public class SynchTest
{
  private static Object[] objs = new Object[3];

  static
  {
    objs[0] = new Object( );
    objs[1] = new Object( );
    objs[2] = new Object( );
  }

  public static Object getObject(int i)
  {
    return objs[i]
  }
}
```

and that objects running in multiple threads call the method getObject(int i). In this case, is it necessary to declare getObject(int i) syncchronized? I wouldn't think so because the objs array is initialized in a static block and never changed. But I'd like a sanity check :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that your code uses actual objects of some class useful to your program, not simply `new Object()` objects.

Comment: The class loading process including the static block happens before any methods of the class are called so you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, when an object is initialized in a `static` initialization block and is never written after that there is no need to make your getter `synchronized`.

Note that this does not make your program thread-safe: although the access to elements of the object array does not need synchronization, access to the individual object properties may need to be synchronized if these objects are *mutable*.

Comment: Looking through the memory model part of the JLS, I see no mention of special semantics for non `final` `static` fields. Could you explain a bit further why this is safe?

Comment: @Raedwald The only thing that JLS needs to guarantee is that the `static` constructor finishes executing before any method can be called on the `SynchTest`, and the spec does guarantee that. After that, there is no concurrent writing, because there is no writing at all. In fact, OP could declare the array `final` if he wanted to.

Comment: ... ah, I see it now. The *Detailed Initialization Procedure* talks about locking during class initialization,  and thus the set up of a `static` field.

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is totally wrong!** But I've left it here because the reasons why it's wrong took me by surprise.  See the comment thread for more.

---

Assuming the data that is "gotten" is immutable, or you know it won't be changed by the threads, then so long as the data is *set* before any other threads are in a state to call the getter, then you are fine.

In general, data that is only read by multiple threads is always thread-safe.

Comment: "In general, data that is only read by multiple threads is always thread-safe." I believe this statement is false.

Comment: @Raedwald Can you give an example?

Comment: Well, no data is *only read*, it is written to at least once, during object construction or initialization. That write needs to be safely published, for which there are various means, but not every constructed value is safely published.

Comment: @Raedwald Could you, or are you aware of any references that explain write publishing? I couldn't find anything myself, though perhaps I don't know what terms to search for.

Comment: *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz talks about safe publication.

Comment: Well that *is* interesting, turns out synchronisation does a lot more that I thought!